# inserting multiple dependent tables at once in sqlite3 using node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I get data from a HTML form, I would like to save this data into **two** dependent tables.

At the moment I came up with the following node.js code:

```
  ...
          db.serialize(function() {
          var lastID;
          db.run('INSERT INTO Idea(title,description) VALUES(?1,?2)', {
              1: formData.nameText,
              2: formData.ideaText
            }, function(err){
              if (err) {
                return console.log(err.message);
              }
              // get the last insert id
              console.log(`A row has been inserted into Idea with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
              lastID = this.lastID;
              console.log(`last inner ID ` + lastID);
            });
          db.run('INSERT INTO Places(lon,lat,IdeaID) VALUES(?1,?2,?3)', {
              1: formData.lon,
              2: formData.lat,
              3: lastID
            }, function(err){
              if (err) {
                return console.log(err.message);
              }
              // get the last insert id
              console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
              console.log(`IdeaID in db ` + lastID);
            });
          db.close();
        })
```

The console output looks good, the database data however isn't.
The console shows:

```
A row has been inserted into Idea with rowid 75
last inner ID 75
A row has been inserted with rowid 16
IdeaID in db 75
```

Inside the database the lastID stays `null`.

Am I missing something? Is this the wrong way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue (with a phone call to my brother). Here is my solution:

```
        db.serialize(function () {
          var lastID;
          db.run('INSERT INTO Idea(title,description) VALUES(?1,?2)', {
            1: formData.nameText,
            2: formData.ideaText
          }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              return console.log(err.message);
            }
            // get the last insert id
            console.log(`A row has been inserted into Idea with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
            db.run('INSERT INTO Places(lon,lat,IdeaID) VALUES(?1,?2,?3)', {
              1: formData.lon,
              2: formData.lat,
              3: this.lastID
            }, function (err) {
              if (err) {
                return console.log(err.message);
              }
              // get the last insert id
              console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
            });
            db.close();
          });
        })
```

This works because the callback (last part of the first db.run call) is executed after the first part.
One important bit is to move the `db.close();` inside the callback, otherwise the connection to the database will be closed before the part inside the callback is executed.